# Web browser/Software that search several search engines at the same time

Tags: search-engines

Is there software that I can install to perform search on many search engines/portal at the same time.

I'm doing a lot of research and I would need to check on google, bing, yahoo and so on at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are services on the web for that kind of thing, aptly named [*Meta search engine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasearch_engine). Wikipedia has [a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Metasearch_engines).

Comment: Dogpile - that brings back memories. 1996 - I must have been using it when it first came out.

Answer (score 3):

[**Copernic Agent**](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/agent/) is what you're looking for. The basic version is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search each of the search engines individually you could use [Shortmarks](http://shortmarks.com) (a service I created).  To search any number of search engines at once from the address bar, create a bundle and give it a keyword of say, s.  Then you could type: `!s <search phrase>` in the address bar to open each of the search results pages in a different tab.